# Data Duplication PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

below is my code that duplicates database entries, what could the problem be?

When I try to trigger the end point that fetches employees it duplicates the entries multiple times

```php
$all_employees = Employee::with([
    'department',
    'sub_department',
    'first_supervisor',
    'second_supervisor',
    'reportingTo',
])
    ->select(
        'employees.*',
        'attendance_times.start_time as attendance_time',
        'cities.city',
        'countries.country',
        'pay_frequencies.frequency as pay_frequency',
        'duty_types.name as duty_type',
        'rate_types.name as rate_type',
        'positions.name as  position_name',
        'departments.department as sub_department',
        'supervisors.name as supervisor_name'
    )
    ->leftJoin('positions', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.position_id', '=', 'positions.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('countries', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.country_id', '=', 'countries.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('supervisors', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.first_supervisor_id', '=', 'supervisors.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('cities', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.city_id', '=', 'cities.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('attendance_times', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.attendance_time_id', '=', 'attendance_times.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('departments', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.sub_department_id', '=', 'departments.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('pay_frequencies', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.pay_frequency_id', '=', 'pay_frequencies.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('duty_types', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.duty_type_id', '=', 'duty_types.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('rate_types', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('employees.rate_type', '=', 'rate_types.id');
    })
    ->orderBy('employees.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();

return $this->customSuccessResponseWithPayload($all_employees);
```

Comment: you can group by with employees id.

Comment: I have not got you sir

Comment: It duplicates mainly the last row

Comment: You do `with` and then `leftJoin` I suggest you only do `with` and access related models through their parent model

Comment: @DenisMulindwa this happened because you try to create your own custom query, why are you not using relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by adding the `groupBy(employees.id)` at the end of the query that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `distinct` with the query to fetch non-repetitive data.

```php
DB::table('table')
    ->select('job_id')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks i have solved it using the groupBy instead of orderBy

Answer (score 0):

Use `with('Relation')` while getting One to Many relation's data, because if you use `leftJoin`, you will get all the relation's data again.

Example:
Every Employee has many `attendance_times`, so if you create an SQL Query which gets all `Employees` and joined the `attendance_times`, the returned data will contain a duplicated EMP data every time it has `attendance_times`.

Basically use `->with('Relation')`.